# ACF Plugin How to make the customer add more fields in the post?

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Example: I created a field with the name, "my-field", there can add it on the post, with a button "add another item" is that I want to create a list with several items, we only need to create multiple fields thus the client how they want to add.

Further explained: I created a "Text" field in the "Advanced Custom Fields" to Custom Post Type: "tariff", the field is for notes, example of how it would look on the panel:

Remarks:
1 - Note 1 | + add one more observation

Then the customer clicked on "+ add one more observation" to automatically add a new field.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [Repeater Add-on for ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) is for:

> The Repeater field acts as a table of data where you can define the columns (sub fields) and add infinite rows.

Unfortunately it's not free, but the one license fee covers you for infinite number of installs on multiple sites.